# Removing XSSFTable from XSSFWorkbook

Tags: apache-poi, xssf

i struggling to remove a table from a `XSSFWorkbook`.

I already tried to remove all columns from a table, which leads to an `IllegalArgumentException: Table must have at least one column` expection.

The Apache POI exposes only methods to remove individual columns, which leads to the described exception.

An another thread references a possible solution

```
for (XSSFTable table : sheet.getTables()) {
         workbook.removePartRelation(table, true);
}
```

by removing relations from a `workbook`. The current API doesn't expose a `removePartRelation`, though. In addition, the possible replacement  `removeRelation` is `protected`.

Is there another possibility to remove tables from a `XSSFWorkbook`?

Comment: Do you want to "remove" the columns or "clear the contents" of the columns?

Comment: I want to remove a complete table from a workbook. Currently, the header dropdown indicator stays in the document.